# recursion of objects and methods in python

Tags: python, recursion

I wanna create a class  which consist of parents and children and a recursion method to call the last **child** :

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,val,child =None):
        self.val = val
        self.child = child
    def findLastChildVal(self):
        if self.child ==None:
            return self.val
        return (...)

c = MyClass("I'm child")
p = MyClass("I'm parent",c)
p.findLastChildVal()
```

I have no Idea what to write instead of (...). It's confusing.

Comment: `return self.child.findLastChildVal()`

Comment: can you add your child classes, to make your code more complete

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: I'm pretty sure it's the same class (the provided code implies this fact quite explicitly).

Comment: Why do you need recursion?

Comment: @reza Also you are passing the  object to the class again, where is the child here?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I've tried ```self.child.findLastChildVal()``` but it didn't work seems chaining  in python is not defined like java script.

Comment: What do you mean "did not work"? What exactly are you expecting to see? Since there's no `print` anywhere in your code, I would expect to see... nothing.

Comment: @reza nothing to do with chaining. `return self.child.findLastChildVal()` works just fine here. Post your non-working code if you can't get it to work.

Comment: @MarkMeyer that's my code and  I get Errors and absolutely I wrote ``` print ````

Comment: @reza what error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic recursion problem, in my opinion it will be much easier to use a static function instead of a member function:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, val, child =None):
        self.val = val
        self.child = child

    @staticmethod
    def find_last_child_val(current_node: MyClass):
        if current_node.child == None:
            return current_node.val
        else:
            return MyClass.find_last_child_val(current_node.child)

c = MyClass("I'm child")
p = MyClass("I'm parent", c)
MyClass.find_last_child_val(p)
```

**Update:**

Pay attention that searching for a child using a recursion like this, is not efficient. `find_last_child_val()` runs in O(n) complexity. It is much more efficient to perform n iterations in a for loop instead of a recursion. If you can't think of a way to reduce the tree traversal complexity, I suggest using a different data structure.